# Pygame - Moving a square around pygame window but cannot stop current movement when changing direction, resulting in the square moving diagonally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

I am using the following code (which is in a loop) to move a square around a pygame window:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                vel_y = -25
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                vel_y = 25
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                vel_x = - 25
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                vel_x= 25
    y += vel_y
    x += vel_x
```

x and y are the position of the square.

This code continuously moves the square in the direction I want it to when pressing an arrow key. However, I ran into the problem of it moving diagonally around the screen if I press up or down and then left or right.

I need a solution to stop it moving in the current direction and changing to the new direction. Not moving in both directions at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the additional key is pressed, the other `vel_` is still set to a value. To fix this, all you need to do is set the other velocity to 0 when you set a new direction.

```
if event.key == K_UP:
    vel_y = -25
    vel_x = 0
elif event.key == K_DOWN:
    vel_y = 25
    vel_x = 0
elif event.key == K_LEFT:
    vel_x = -25
    vel_y = 0
elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
    vel_x = 25
    vel_y = 0
```